# How to update table with data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery, inner-join

I have two tables

First table `INTRA.TABLE_A`

```
id  | first_value | second_value
----------------------------------
1   |    1234     |    181818
2   |    1235     |    1919191
3   |    1236     |    2384
```

Second table `EXTRA.TABLE_B`

```
id  | first_value | second_value
----------------------------------
1   |    1235     |    1919191
2   |    1236     |    0
3   |    1234     |    0
4   |    1234     |    181818
5   |    1234     |    0
6   |    1236     |    0
```

And I am trying to get data from `INTRA.TABLE_A` into `EXTRA.TABLE_B` with update:

```
UPDATE B
SET
    B.SECOND_VALUE = A.SECOND_VALUE
FROM
    EXTRA.TABLE_B B,
    INTRA.TABLE_A A
WHERE
    A.FIRST_VALUE = B.FIRST_VALUE
    AND B.SECOND_VALUE = 0;
```

But it "throws" syntax error at `FROM` word:

[syntax_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm0v7.png)

After update, result should looks like:

```
id  | first_value | second_value
----------------------------------
1   |    1235     |    1919191
2   |    1236     |    2384
3   |    1234     |    181818
4   |    1234     |    181818
5   |    1234     |    181818
6   |    1236     |    2384
```

I am using sqlDeveloper and Oracle database. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle does not support joins in `update` queries - unlike other database, such as SQL Server (in which the query you are using would probably run just as it is).

I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
update table_b b
set second_value = (select a.second_value from tablea a where a.first_value = b.first_value)
where b.second_value = 0
```

You might want to add a condition to ensure that only "matching" rows are updated:

```
update table_b b
set second_value = (select a.second_value from tablea a where a.first_value = b.first_value)
where 
    b.second_value = 0
    and exists (select a.second_value from tablea a where a.first_value = b.first_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would `MERGE` do any good?

```
MERGE INTO table_b b
     USING table_a a
        ON (a.FIRST_VALUE = b.FIRST_VALUE)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET b.second_value = a.second_value;
```